# Something is wrong when my player is jumping on walls

Tags: unity, jumping

When my player jump beside walls and it reached the top of the wall, it's forcing the player to stop at the point of top of the wall. Like if my player y is higher than the y of the wall, it's making me stop. And I am using Character Controller. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/tVVXaBqaVKQ)

This is how I implemented my jump:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    #region Variables

    [Header("Required Variables")]
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Slider energyBar;

    [Header("Movement and Gravity")]
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 2.75f;
    public float gravity = -19.62f;
    public bool affectedByTimeScale = true;

    [Header("Configureable values")]
    public float maxEnergy = 100f;
    public float energyDrainAmount = 1f;
    public float energyGainAmount = 1f;
    public float cooldownBeforeGaining = 0.75f;
    
    CharacterController controller;
    Target target;
    Vector3 lastVelocityBeforeGrounded, velocity, move;
    float x, z, baseTime;
    bool jumping, running, grounded, moving;

    #endregion


    private void Awake() {
        if (affectedByTimeScale) baseTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        else baseTime = Time.fixedUnscaledDeltaTime;

        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        target = GetComponent<Target>();

        lastVelocityBeforeGrounded = Vector3.zero;
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        move = Vector3.zero;

        energyBar.maxValue = maxEnergy;
        energyBar.value = maxEnergy;
    }


    private void Update() {
        MyInput();
        Movement();
    }


    private void MyInput()
    {
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        jumping = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
        running = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

        if (x == 0 && z == 0) moving = false;
        else moving = true;
    }


    float counter = 0f;
    private void Movement()
    {
        Gravity();
        move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        CheckGround();

        if (jumping) Jump();
        if (running && moving && energyBar.value > 0)
        {
            move.x *= 1.5f;
            move.z *= 1.5f;
            energyBar.value -= energyDrainAmount;
            counter = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            move.x /= 1.5f;
            move.z /= 1.5f;
            
            if (counter == 0f) counter = Time.time + cooldownBeforeGaining;
            if (Time.time > counter) energyBar.value += energyGainAmount;
        }

        controller.Move(move * baseTime * moveSpeed);
    }


    private void CheckGround()
    {
        grounded = controller.isGrounded;
        if (grounded)
        {
            // F = (V^2/2)
            if (lastVelocityBeforeGrounded.y < -10f)
            {
                float velY = Mathf.Abs(lastVelocityBeforeGrounded.y);
                float damage = Mathf.Pow(velY, 2) / 2;
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            velocity.y = -2f;
            lastVelocityBeforeGrounded = Vector3.zero;
        }
        else lastVelocityBeforeGrounded = velocity;
    }


    private void Jump()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * -2f * gravity);
        }
    }


    private void Gravity()
    {
        velocity.y += gravity * baseTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * baseTime);
    }


}
```

This is my Camera Controller script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    #region Variables

    [Header("Required Variables")]
    public Transform orientation;
    public Transform player;

    [Header("Assignable Variables")]
    public float sensitivity = 65f;
    public bool affectedByTimeScale = true;
    
    float baseTime, xRotation, sensMultiplier;

    #endregion


    private void Awake() {
        if (affectedByTimeScale) baseTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        else baseTime = Time.fixedUnscaledDeltaTime;

        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

        xRotation = 0f;
        sensMultiplier = 10f;
    }


    private void FixedUpdate() {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * baseTime * (sensitivity * sensMultiplier);
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * baseTime * (sensitivity * sensMultiplier);

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        orientation.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        transform.position = orientation.position;
        transform.rotation = orientation.rotation;
    }


}
```

`This is my player setup:`
[image]

`This is the variables inside camera controller:`
[image]

Comment: Besides the screen video, it would help a lot if you post your code on how you implement your jump.

Comment: Can you take a look what's wrong in my code? or what makes it behave like that?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error with a few stacked cubes but can only jump once. Now the question is, could your stairs maybe not smooth and there is a tiny edge you manage to land on one that allows you to do another jump? Your camera look script is just adjusting the camera and not the player, right?

Comment: I have an orientation inside the player which makes the camera follow the position of player (because my player is not a parent of camera).

Comment: If you use a single cube and scale it (10, 10, 1) to make it a wall, can you still jump to its top?

Comment: I can't, it's only triggering when my highest point of jump is higher than the wall (and I am putting force on the wall)

Comment: In my case, my highest jump point is lower than the wall because I scaled the y.

Comment: At around 18sec in your video you attempt to jump at the back of the stairs, which is higher than your controller can jump and you still end up at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117762/discussion-between-zibelas-and-adolfjames-urian).